# Form field parameters get messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am submitting a form, this is the part in question

```
<% item.question_options.sort.each do |opt| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag('responder[selected_options][' + item.id.to_s + '][][option_id]', opt.id.to_s, @responder.answered_to?(opt, item))%> 
  <%= text_field_tag('responder[selected_options][' + item.id.to_s + '][][content]', @responder.get_response_for_option(item, opt, lang.id)%>
<% end %>
```

These are the generated tags. There are two questions, each is a radio button with an optional text field.

```
<input id="responder_selected_options_183__option_id_137" type="radio" value="137" name="0701b[selected_options][183][][option_id]">
<input id="responder_selected_options_183__content" type="text" name="0701b[selected_options][183][][content]">

<input id="responder_selected_options_183__option_id_138" type="radio" value="138" name="0701b[selected_options][183][][option_id]">
<input id="responder_selected_options_183__content" type="text" name="0701b[selected_options][183][][content]">
```

If the first radio button chosen, and content given to the corresponding field, it creates parameters as expected:

```
"183"=>[{"option_id"=>"137", "content"=>"smth"}, {"content"=>""}]
```

However, if the content is given to the first field and the second radio button is chosen, the parameters are like this:

```
"183"=>[{"content"=>"smth", "option_id"=>"138"}, {"content"=>""}]
```

..while I would expect them to be like this:

```
"183"=>[{"content"=>"smth"}, {"option_id"=>"138", "content"=>""}]
```

Why does this happen and how could I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem the way I wanted. I ended up creating a new array for `content` variables and handle things differently in models.

```
<%= radio_button_tag('responder[selected_options][' + item.id.to_s + '][]', opt.id.to_s, @responder.answered_to?(opt, item), :disabled => @responder.finished?)%>
<%= text_field_tag('responder[options_content][' + item.id.to_s + ']['+opt.id.to_s+']',  @responder.get_response_for_option(item, opt, lang.id), :disabled => @responder.finished?, :class => "form-control")%>
```

this gives back nice arrays with everything I need, without a mess up.

```
"selected_options"=>{"183"=>["137"]}, 
"options_content"=>{"183"=>{"137"=>"", "138"=>"smth"}}}}
```